# How to pass to a vertex-shader dynamic data that should apply for all vertices?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-3, vertex-shader

I've a simple program that draws an object, and I want its position to ultimately respond to user-input.

I've tried to create a buffer object with just 2 GLfloats to hold the position and pass it in location 1, and learned that it only affects the first vertex (which actually makes sense, now that I think about it).
I've thought about using uniforms but it doesn't seem to be the correct way either (I've read that changing them can be slow).

What's the approach to this in OpenGL 3/4?

Comment: `learned that it only affects the first vertex` Where did you learn that? Vertex attributes are per-vertex; uniforms affect all vertex in a draw command.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Experience - I tried it and that's what happened. I do want to affect all vertices (as I want to translate the entire object), which is why I considered uniforms but as I mentioned, it doesn't seem a good way.

Comment: Uniforms are completely appropriate for passing a transformation matrix to a shader.

Comment: Well, if you pass a constant vertex attribute instead of setting up a vertex pointer, you will get a constant value across all vertices. But that's something different. Just use a vertex buffer with the appropriate size.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I can see why, but are they also a *good* choice for dynamic data? I'll have to update the uniform after every single frame.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman What do you mean? isn't setting up a vertex pointer the way to pass a vertex attribute? And when you say the appropriate size - do you mean to replicate the position again and again for every vertex? (if so, it seems like it would be discouraged, doesn't it?)

Comment: I wasn't sure exactly what you were trying to do. If you want to fetch these attributes using an `in` attribute, then you should consider using a command like `glVertexAttrib4f (...)` for example to set a constant value.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman What's the difference between this and uniforms, other than using `in` vs `uniform`?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Mostly just storage and associated limits. Implementations are required to support a minimum of 16 4-component vertex attributes and 1024 4-component uniforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this either by using uniforms or vertex attributes. I would suggest using a vertex attribute in the event that you ever want the vertices to have a unique value per-vertex. You can achieve that simply by supplying a vertex pointer instead of a constant vertex attribute.

#### The following command applies a constant value to every instance of a vertex attribute:

`glVertexAttrib{1|2|3|4}f[v] (...)`